# How to make <f1> display in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

On a post in my WordPress installation, there are these four lines:

```
map <f1> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
imap <f2> <esc>:w <cr>:!python %<cr>
map <f3> :w myScript.py<cr>:!python %<cr>
imap <f4> :w myScript.py<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

When I publish it,  and  lost.

```
map  :w:!python %
imap  :w :!python %
map  :w myScript.py:!python %
imap  :w myScript.py:!python %
```

How can I make it so it displays properly?

[image]
[image]

It doesn't work to use `<pre>` at the beginning and end of the text.

[image: before published <pre> in it]

Published:

[image: published]

How can i make the wordpress to be WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get)?

Comment: try using `<pre>` or `&lt;`/`&gt;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work

```
 map &lt;f1&gt; :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
 imap &lt;f2&gt; <esc>:w <cr>:!python %<cr>
 map &lt;f3&gt; :w myScript.py<cr>:!python %<cr>
 imap &lt;f4&gt; :w myScript.py<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

Use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `%gt;` for `>`

Comment: map &lt;f1&gt; :w<cr>:!python %&lt;cr&gt;  is display into  ` map <f1> :w:!python %<cr>`,How can i make the wordpress to be WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get)?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Wordpress renders texts enclosed in '</>' as HTML tags. If you're using a Wordpress installation, there are plugins you can add to enable WYSIWYG of code-like strings. Examples are [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wysiwyg-inline-code-command) or [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/escape-html/)